# Connect wi-fi from my application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

[image]

I am developing Out-of-box experience application. I have to connect
   wi-fi from my customised application with out using device wifi
   setup.
       I have done, getting wi-fi network list from wifi manager.

Could you please guide me, how to connect wifi from my application?

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(WifiActivity.this);
                    str_wifi_nt_name = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    alert.setTitle(str_wifi_nt_name);
                    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(WifiActivity.this);
                    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(20, 0, 30, 0);
                    wifi_password = new EditText(WifiActivity.this);
                    wifi_password.setHint("wi-fi password");
                    str_wifi_password=wifi_password.getText().toString();
                    layout.addView(wifi_password, params);
                    alert.setView(layout);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                            wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", str_wifi_nt_name);
                            wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", str_wifi_password);
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();
            }

        });
    }
```

how to set given password to wifi manager.could u please healp me.

Comment: Can you make clear what you need exactly because is not clear.

Comment: 1.on wifi 2.get wifi networks 3.connect wifi from my application only.                  1 and 2  completed. WiFi connection to done from my application with out using device wifi set up.   I have attached screen shot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent resetIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR");
                            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(SHUTDOWN_INTENT_EXTRA, false)) {
                             resetIntent.putExtra(SHUTDOWN_INTENT_EXTRA, true);
                                 }
                            sendBroadcast(resetIntent);
```